# Lot of Work in doInBackground() - thread suspended - frames skipped

Tags: android, json, multithreading, android-asynctask

I have a simple asynctask and in the doInBackground(). The problem is, it is really too much work to do..at least **35000 nodes** in a json.

And then I have:

```
I/Choreographer: Skipped 41 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

W/art: Suspending all threads took: 33.923ms

I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 20(672B) AllocSpace objects, 1(9MB) LOS objects, 11% free, 47MB/53MB, paused 2.674ms total 102.623ms

W/art: Suspending all threads took: 20.574ms

I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 65195(2MB) AllocSpace objects, 20(11MB) LOS objects, 28% free, 40MB/56MB, paused 20.163ms total 89.164ms

I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 166274(6MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 10% free, 50MB/56MB, paused 1.755ms total 118.003ms

I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 68708(2MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 22% free, 54MB/70MB, paused 2.229ms total 134.658ms

I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 174470(6MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 7% free, 64MB/70MB, paused 2.596ms total 163.746ms

W/art: Suspending all threads took: 48.574ms
```

Here my asynctask doInBackground(). I used a real device..not an emulator. I don't know what to do since I need to do other stuff with the json. How I can avoid the thread suspensions and all the warning and skipping frames?

```
@Override
protected ArrayList<MarkerOptions> doInBackground(Void... params) {

    try {
        url = new URL("http://xxxxxxxx.php");
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
        jsonString=readStream(in);


    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        urlConnection.disconnect();
    }


    try {
        mainJsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);

        JSONArray ja = mainJsonObject.getJSONArray("font");
        Log.d("fontanelle",ja.length()+"");

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

I think I found my problem.

the method read() tooks lot of time to process all the information. This is the method:

```
    private String readStream(InputStream is) {
    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bo = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
       Log.d("time", SystemClock.currentThreadTimeMillis()+"  startRead");
        int i = is.read();

        while (i != -1) {
            bo.write(i);
            i = is.read();
        }
     Log.d("time", SystemClock.currentThreadTimeMillis()+"  StopRead");

        return bo.toString();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return "";
    }
}
```

The same for JSONArray ja = mainJsonObject.getJSONArray("font");

There are any more efficient way to read?

Comment: That isn't what's causing the problem, unless you're doing something silly like calling doInBackground directly on the main thread.  Async tasks are executed on another thread.  Your problem is on the main.

Comment: mmm..I don't know what you mean. In the Main I did :
' myTask task; task = new myTask(); task.execute();'
 I have nothing more. It is not the right way to call an asynctask?

Comment: That's the right way.  What I mean is that task isn't your problem, unless its just using ungodly amounts of memory.  Your problem is somewhere else.

Comment: I was thinking the same think..so I created a new project with nothing more. Only an asyncTask called in the main and the problem still happens.